# Rewrite URL and redirect by .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How i can redirect these :

```
http://www.example.com/content/news/578442798  
and:
http://www.example.com/content/news/578442798/something_extra
```

to this (a slash in end):

```
   http://www.example.com/content/news/578442798/
```

and i want `something_extra` at end of the second url be ineffective

htaccess is really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/external/MyProj/

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)(/.+|$) display/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Note that i'm trying this on localhost then update original.
when i click , redirects to 'http://localhost/news/466767066/'
and shows 404

Comment: If rule redirects to `http://localhost/news/466767066/` then it is behaving as per the question. I don't know your setup to guess why it is causing 404. When you directly enter `http://localhost/news/466767066/` in your browser does it work and shows proper content?

Comment: i do not want to remove 'somethings_extra'.  i want to be there but ineffective.

Comment: I think there is some misconception in your thoughts. You wrote you want final URL in the browser as `http://www.example.com/news/578442798/` is that not the case?

Comment: yeah excuse me. i want everything after `example.com/news/5784427` be ineffective.

Comment: Ok not sure what you mean by `everything after example.com/news/5784427 be ineffective` but I modified my answer to do internal rewrite only.

Comment: `example.com/news/5784427/everythingsadfsdf`
`example.com/news/5784427/everythingasd`
`example.com/news/5784427/everythingasd`
`example.com/news/5784427/everythingaaaadfsdfsdfdf`

be equal to `example.com/news/5784427/`   :|

Comment: Guys,have you any idea for this ?
How i make this url :

`www.example.com/content/news/123456/something`

equal to :

`www.example.com/content/news/123456/somethingsomethingsomething`

i mean the phrase after `123456` be traceless and can be anything.
help me ):

Comment: As I wrote this rule is already doing it. Whatever comes after `/news/123456/any-thing-here` is ignored and rewritten to `/news/123456/`

Comment: i get 404 error ):
note :my content are not in root directory.

Comment: Ok you never told this before. In which directory do you have it?

Comment: `http://localhost/xampp/external/MyProj/display/index.php`  the `MyProj` is main page.  i used `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ ./display/index.php?id=$1` to correct url

Comment: Thaaaanksssssss.you solved my allover today problem.

Comment: I have provided my LinkedIn link in my profile. Also you should remove your comment from question. I upvoted your question to neutralize somebody's downvote. It is better to describe your problem clearly and show your attempt to solve it.